# while printing div goes inside text box

Tags: html, css, printing, css-float

For a normal web page I am trying to print the page for a A4 size.....
the webpage is working fine without the printing......
when i see the page after printing the last div goes inside the text box....
how to make the last div stay on the right.....

http://jsfiddle.net/D7vgU/embedded/result/

```
<div style=" width: 300px; display: inline-block; position: relative; bottom: 39px; float: right;">

  <span style="color: #000; font-size: 12px; font-family: arial; font-wieght: bold; margin-left: 45px;">
    Mark Up
  </span>
  <span style="margin-left: 110px;">
    10%
  </span>

  <div>

    <span style="margin-left: 45px;">
      Non-Tax Amount
    </span>
    <span style="margin-left: 59px;">
      0
    </span>

  </div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

You could use:

```
<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" media="print" href="print.css">
```

or

```
@media print {/*printer only styles here*/}
```

Comment: :no i am not using it...what is the use of it....i using media for print in css but not in html